Adjust winrates based on number of games played using Bayesian estimator
I am sorting players of an online video games based on their winrate, but I'm trying to use the number of games they scored that winrate on. The idea behind it is that even though 9 wins for 1 losse theoretically represents a better winrate (0.9) than 17 wins for 2 losses (~0.89), the latter is more impressive because the player was able to maintain it across more games, thus making it more meaningful and impressive.
My datasets vary and I think I need to mention the two categories I'm dealing with because I think it might impact the overall problem as I'm trying to develop a method that will work for both cases. So these datasets are basically subsets of a huge playerbase (talking about millions here) and each contains players wins and losses for a specific character in the game. A player needs to have played at least 10 games with a character in order to be present in the corresponding subset. Each subset can contain up to 5000 players (i.e. their number of wins and their number of losses). The fact that they can contain up to 5000 players is important, because it means when a subset contain $<5000$ players, it contains the entirety of the playerbase that played more than 10 games with that character (i.e. good and bad players), whereas when a subset contains exactly $5000$ players, it means it is itself a subset of a bigger subset containing players that player more than 10 games with the characters (i.e. best players). In the second case, I have no way to get the missing stats (its size, mean, variance... etc), nor know how these 5000 players were selected, except that the selection roughly uses winrate as well as other statistics. So to summarize, when its size is below $<5000$ the total players for a character, when a subset contains less than 5000 players their winrate can be good or bad because it represents to actual entirety of the spectrum, whereas when a subset contains exactly 5000 players their winrate will most likely be good because it represents the higher part of the spectrum but the actual spectrum size is unknown.
Here are two data samplings to illustrate what I mean :


Be careful, the ranking changes depending on the winrate used, each x doesn't correspond to the same player.
So far I found out about Bayes estimator on a Reddit post and even though at first I thought it was some obscure technique, I gave it a try and sorted my data based on the new modified winrates and it ended up working quite well on my data, even though I don't really understand why or how. Basically I compute from the dataset its total number of wins $W$, its total number of losses $L$, its global winrate $\overline{r}=\frac{W}{W+L}$, its global winrate variance, a factor $f=\frac{\overline{r}(1-\overline{r})}{v}-1$ and two parameters $\alpha=\overline{r}\times f$ and $\beta=(1-\overline{r})\times f$. Then I compute each new winrate $\frac{w+\alpha}{w+\alpha+l+\beta}$.
Is it valid ? If so, is it the way to go with this kind of problem ?
Once sorted, I need to process them from the very best (hence the first sorting step) to the least acceptable for my problem, so I need some kind of threshold but since I don't really understand what I did in the previous step, I'm having difficulties interpreting this, thus setting that threshold. Setting it was quite easy when dealing with original winrates because this value actually represent something I'm familiar with and could easily set the threshold, but since this new metric is dynamically generated, I'm a bit at loss, and even more when I think about the nature of my datasets, I'm wondering how it can impact the new winrates and the way I need to interpret them.
The only idea I have will be to sort using the new adjusted winrates but still use the normal winrate which is more "universal" so I don't need really need to bother understanding this new winrate anymore, just to make sure its ranking is good in the two cases I mentionned at the beginning of the post.
